# Why this happens with cucumber test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, cucumber

I have scenario like this

```
Given /^initial data$/ do |table|
  @schedule_05 = Factory.build :schedule_05
  @schedule_05.save
  puts "count of rows #{@schedule_05.cycles.count}" - # is 7
end
#....... there are same steps and where filling text fields and so on/

When /^i click a submit button "([^"]*)" in form$/ do |runs|
  click_button(runs) # this is ajax request
end

Then /^count of SchOfWorkInformation is 365$/ do 
  puts "count of rows #{ScheduleOfWorking.count}" # is - 1
  s_c = ScheduleOfWorking.find_by_schedule_code("05") # is too 1
  puts "05 schedule is presents #{s_c.blank?}" # false
  unless s_c.blank?
    puts "05 schedule is presents #{s_c.date_of_countings.blank?}" #false
  end
end
```

In step when i click submit involves a controller ScheduleOfWorkingController's filling action

```
def filling
unless request.xhr?
  @classifier_schedule = ScheduleOfWorking.classifiers_numbers
  @schedule_number = ScheduleOfWorking.classifiers_numbers false
else
  if params[:date_begin].blank? || params[:date_end].blank?
    render :js => "alert('date fields is empty !')"
    return
  end
  ScheduleOfWorking.fill_information_for(params[:date_begin].to_date,params[:date_end].to_date)
end
```

end

ScheduleOfWorking#fill_information_for

```
def self.fill_information_for(date_begin, date_end)
  sch = all
  sch.each do |e_sch|
    e_sch.date_of_countings.each do |d_counting|
      h_calculate = d_counting.roll_cycle(date_begin, date_end)
      transaction do
        SchOfWorkInformation.delete_all("(date >= '#{date_begin}' and date <= '#{date_end}') and schedule_code = #{d_counting.sch_code}")

        SchOfWorkInformation.create! h_calculate 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In SchOfWorkInformation i have custom validation method like this

```
def customer_validate
s = SchOfWorkInformation.where(:date => self.date, :schedule_code => self.schedule_code).first

if !s.blank? && (new_record? || s.id != self.id)
  self.errors[:base] = "Запись не уникально!(date=#{self.date.to_s(:db)}, schedule_code=#{self.schedule_code})"
end

sch_number = schedule_code[0..1].blank? ? "0" : schedule_code[0..1]
session_number = schedule_code[2].blank? ? "0" : schedule_code[2]
logger.info "---------------------------------------"
ss_a = ScheduleOfWorking.all

s = ScheduleOfWorking.where("schedule_code='#{sch_number}'").
                      joins(:date_of_countings).
                      where("date_countings.session_number=#{session_number}")
  # In Given section of my step i load the data, but s.balnk? gives true
  if s.blank?
    self.errors[:base] = "Schedule - #{sch_number} with session number #{session_number}), is not exists in DB"
  end
end
```

Why my data lose in validation method? Help, please!

In development env. all rights, but in test not.

..sorry for long letter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What database strategy are you using for these tests? If it's running in a transaction, the data is never actually persisted to the database. You should be using some other method for these steps since the data is guaranteed to be persisted regardless of how many threads or processes are running. When you make an ajax request, it's in a separate request to the server and the database transaction is only available to that request.

In my application, I have a setting for the javascript tests that uses a shared connection:

```
Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :shared_connection
```

Comment: I passed  Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :shared_connection  in env.rb, but now i get   Mysql2::Error: This connection is still waiting for a result, try again once you have the result:  in my server log..

Comment: It's because the ajax request is asynchronous and cucumber moves to the next step before it finishes the reqeust. You have a couple options including waiting for the event to finish before moving to the next step or locating some element on the page and forcing it to wait.

Comment: Here's an example http://pivotallabs.com/users/mgehard/blog/articles/1671-waiting-for-jquery-ajax-calls-to-finish-in-cucumber or check out the AJAX section here for more info https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara